# Convert GUID to 8-4-4-4-12 format in javascript

Tags: javascript, uuid, guid

I am looking to convert a GUID such as `18d874986a114520bd29466a446a50eb` to the format `18d87498-6a11-4520-bd29-466a446a50eb`

Is there a function in Javascript for doing this?

I googled a bit and looks like the 8-4-4-4-12 format is called UUID. I however, do not find any to UUID conversion libraries.

Do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach uses a regex replacement:

```js
var uuid = "18d874986a114520bd29466a446a50eb";
uuid = uuid.replace(/^([a-f0-9]{8})([a-f0-9]{4})([a-f0-9]{4})([a-f0-9]{4})([a-f0-9]{12})$/i, "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5");
console.log(uuid);
```